# Scrollbar doesn't show up

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios programming.

I want users to be able to scroll screen, so I initialized UIScrollView and add other views into the instance of UIScrollView.

But, I'm not able to scroll screen and I don't see a scrollbar.

This is my code I wrote.
This view controller extends from UIViewController.

What is wrong with this?

Please help me.
Thank you very much!!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.png"];
    UIImageView *profileImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    CGPoint newPoint = self.view.center;

    newPoint.y = 300;
    profileImg.center = newPoint;

    [scrollView addSubview:profileImg];


}
```

Comment: Your imageView has no frame. Also, try not to initialize frame of UIScrollView with self.view.frame, but rather use self.view.bounds as you most likely need the size values, not origins.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to try it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set a content size and scroll enabled

```
[scrollView setFrame:self.view.bounds]; // not needed to be able to scroll
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES]; // needed to be able to scroll, defaults to YES
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)]; // the important part that is needed to be able to scroll
```

the 320 and 500 are desired maxed distances of scrolling to, this is not the actual scroll distance but the width and height of pixels that will be shown, you can think of the scroll view being a window and these values being the world outside

that is where you main error is, the width and height of your scroll view is the same width and height of the context size, therefore; it's like you are looking through a 1ft by 1ft window in to a room that is only 1ft by 1ft

[UIScrollView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I'm accepting your answer in 2 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your additional explanation! I got it!

Comment: oh yeah no problem, i ran into the same thing when i was learning scroll views and the likes :D